# How to show a message on process end in website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, system.diagnostics

I want to start a process when i clicked the start button on webpage (asp.net site) now i want to set the label text to process started. and i want to set the label text to "Process Completed " when the process is ended. how to do this in asp.net and C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using update panels or any Ajax/jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using [ASP.NET SignalR](http://signalr.net/). Here's a summary of what it does:

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it
>   incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your
>   applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's **the
>   ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected
>   clients as it happens, in real-time**.

The following is an example of simple web page with a button which starts `Notepad.exe`. Once the process is started, a label on the page shows `process started`. When the process exits (`Notepad` is closed), the label's updates to `process exited`.

So, first create an ASP.NET empty web application project (let's name it *MyWebApplication*) and get the [Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/1.0.1). Add a web form to the project and name it *Test*. Add the following code to the *Test.aspx* file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyWebApplication.Test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Proxy created on the fly          
            var chat = $.connection.chat;
            // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it          
            chat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
                $('#label').text(message);
            };
            // Start the connection
            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Start Notepad.exe"
                        ID="button" OnClick="button_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger 
                        ControlID="button" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <span id="label"></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Add a new class file to your project and name it `Chat`. In *Chat.cs* you will have:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace MyWebApplication
{
    public class Chat : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            //Call the addMessage method on all clients     
            var c = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("Chat");
            c.Clients.All.addMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following to the *Test.aspx.cs* file:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace MyWebApplication
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Chat chat = new Chat();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        void MyProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chat.Send("process exited");
        }

        protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process MyProcess = new Process();
            MyProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
            MyProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            MyProcess.Exited += MyProcess_Exited;
            MyProcess.Start();
            chat.Send("process started");
        }
    }
}
```

Add the *Global.asax* file:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MyWebApplication
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        }
    }
}
```

Some things I haven't covered:

1. The label is updated on all connections.
2. I'm not verifying if the process is already running or not (but that shouldn't be very difficult to check).

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to do the callback. And on each stage; Initiated, Completed or Error; update a label in your html. This should be fairly simple if you look for some samples with jQuery AJAX.

[jQuery AJAX POST example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in CodeBehind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Records Inserted Successfuly", "Showalert();", true);
```

JAVASCRIPT add this in source code (aspx):

```
 function Showalert() {
            alert('Records inserted Successfully!');
        }
```

And do add using System.Web.UI;

**OR**

You can simply add a Label to the webform like this in aspx..

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

and in codebehind aspx.cs add ..

```
Labelname.Text = "whatever msg you wanna display."
```

Comment: I have edited my answer, tell me if you still have any problems..!

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use javascript...what you can do is to change label text first when button click event is fired.

```
lblLabel.text="process started"
```

and last line in button_click event should be like:

```
lblLable.text="process completed";
```